# Add numerical condition to Google Sheets QUERY with IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I am using `IMPORTRANGE` to call and organise some data from another Google Sheet:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("key", "Sheet1!A2:I"), "select Col1, Col2 where Col2 is not null order by Col2")
```

How can I add the condition that `Col2` data should be ignored if not between the numbers 1-5?

And what could I do if Sheets thought the original `Col2` data type was a string and not a number?

Answer (score 2):

Cracked it!

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1qKM3CLVXXUaL2-GK8vnzQqVPa0YtkpAa4MCPQ-b-k2I", "Sheet1!A2:I"), "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6 where Col6 is not null and Col6 > 0 and Col6 <= 5 order by Col6")
```